# Finding span data in element using Selenium C#

Tags: c#

trying to find this span and click on it. There are multiple objects on the page with the same ID. Need to find by data-margin

```
<span title="Add me!" onclick="addCalc(this)" id="chkSelectedPrice" class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked pointer-finger add-calc" data-productid="1534" data-margin="1.375" data-lpc="0" data-unadjustedplf="0.578" data-plf="0.578" data-isfixed="False" data-buyrate="0"></span>
```

Comment: if there are frames present and the element is present within that you will need to include more html. If you right click inspect the element the path including frame should be shown in the browser at the bottom (Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this through xpath. Selenium has built-in xpath support so it should be pretty easy to query for your element

https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Also, if you want to generate an xpath for elements on an existing website you can try this plugin

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/truepath/

I haven't tested this but I think your xpath will be something similar to

```
span[@data-margin="1.375"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath.

```
//span[@data-margin="1.375"]
```

CSS:

```
span[data-margin="1.375"]
```

Comment: Tried this and still no luck finding it.                                                               IWebElement mar1 = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@data-margin= '1.375']"));
mar1.Click();

Comment: what is the error? if you don't get any error then try the mouse click.

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@data-margin= '1.375']"}

Comment: Do you have multiple windows or frames?

Comment: Multiple Frames on the page

Comment: Then you have to switch to the frame where the element is located. currently selenium is trying to find the element in the base window, which might be in one of the frames.